# How to fix the Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in line 378

Tags: php, webserver

I'm having trouble installing modules and extension in Magento. This is the code that's failing:

```
$uriModified = $this->getModifiedUri($uri, $https);
    $this->_ch = curl_init();
    $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_URL, $uriModified);
    $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
    T, 'TLSv1');$this->getCurlMethodSettings($method, $params, $isAuthorizationRequired);

    if(count($this->_headers)) {
        $heads = array();
        foreach($this->_headers as $k=>$v) {
            $heads[] = $k.': '.$v;
        }
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $heads);
    }
```

I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','

On this line:

```
T, 'TLSv1');$this->getCurlMethodSettings($method, $params, $isAuthorizationRequired);
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in what you entered. Of course, we can't be more precise, since you gave us absolutely no information about what you did.

Answer (score 2):

The line you said is failing looks like it duplicates the end of the previous line. This part:

```
T, 'TLSv1');
```

Is the end of the previous line:

```
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
```

I expect you copy/pasted something wrong, and could remove that part, leaving:

```
$this->getCurlMethodSettings($method, $params, $isAuthorizationRequired);
```